# Cannot create token for Moodle 2.5 - "The user hasn't the required capability to use this service"

Tags: web-services, token, moodle

I've just upgraded to Moodle 2.5 and want to create a **token** for a particular user. I created the course, enrolled some users to it and tried to create a token for a user.
On menu `Site administration -> Plugins -> Web services -> Manage tokens` when I choose the user and click to perform the token, the moodle system prints:

```
The user hasn't the required capability to use this service
and link to: http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/error/moodle/nocapabilitytousethisservice
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!

On the Add service page check `Enable` and uncheck `Authorised users` options. Select `No required capability`.

Comment: I have found the option of Enabling Web Services. But I am not getting Disabling Authorised User option. Please help @Dozent.